# Im trying to create a Loop after the code gets to a certain point. How?

Tags: python

How do i create a loop that will re-ask the question of what formula you want? It is supposed to ask if you want to do a formula again. How do you loop it?

```
   print("""
Welcome to the Science Speed, Distance, and Time Formula Caculator!

[1] Speed
[2] Distance
[3] Time

Enter the number NOT the word.
""")
choice1 = int(input("Choose a Formula: "))
if choice1 == 1:  
  print("You have choosen the Speed Formula!")
  D = int(input("Enter the Distance(meters): "))
  T = int(input("Enter the Time(seconds): "))
  Equation = D/T
  print ("Your answer is ",Equation,"m/s.")
  print ("Restart the program to do another equation.(Click Run^^^) This caculator was made in 33 lines of code!")
elif choice1 == 2:  
  print("You have choosen the Distance Formula!")
  S = int(input("Enter the Speed(m/s): "))
  T = int(input("Enter the Time(seconds): "))
  Equation = S*T
  print("Your answer is ",Equation,"meters.")
  print ("Restart the program to do another equation.(Click Run^^^) This caculator was made in 33 lines of code!")
elif choice1 == 3:  
  print("You have choosen the Time Formula!")
  D = int(input("Enter the Distance(meters): "))
  S = int(input("Enter the Speed(m/s): "))
  Equation = D/S 
  print("Your answer is ",Equation,"seconds.")
  print ("Restart the program to do another equation.(Click Run^^^) This caculator was made in 33 lines of code!")
else: 
  print("Restart the program and choose one of the numbers above for the corresponding formula you would like to calculate. This calculator was made in 33 lines of code!")
```

Comment: Some words are spelled wrong like calculator, my bad.

Comment: Feel free to edit the post to fix them :)

Comment: Put `while True:` around the whole thing. Ask the user if they want to try again, and break out of the loop if they say no.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a while loop.

**Ex:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print("""
Welcome to the Science Speed, Distance, and Time Formula Caculator!

[1] Speed
[2] Distance
[3] Time

Enter the number NOT the word.
""")
while True:
    choice1 = int(input("Choose a Formula: "))
    if choice1 == 1:
      print("You have choosen the Speed Formula!")
      D = int(input("Enter the Distance(meters): "))
      T = int(input("Enter the Time(seconds): "))
      Equation = D/T
      print ("Your answer is ",Equation,"m/s.")
      print ("Restart the program to do another equation.(Click Run^^^) This caculator was made in 33 lines of code!")
    elif choice1 == 2:
      print("You have choosen the Distance Formula!")
      S = int(input("Enter the Speed(m/s): "))
      T = int(input("Enter the Time(seconds): "))
      Equation = S*T
      print("Your answer is ",Equation,"meters.")
      print ("Restart the program to do another equation.(Click Run^^^) This caculator was made in 33 lines of code!")
    elif choice1 == 3:
      print("You have choosen the Time Formula!")
      D = int(input("Enter the Distance(meters): "))
      S = int(input("Enter the Speed(m/s): "))
      Equation = D/S
      print("Your answer is ",Equation,"seconds.")
      print ("Restart the program to do another equation.(Click Run^^^) This caculator was made in 33 lines of code!")
    else:
      print("Restart the program and choose one of the numbers above for the corresponding formula you would like to calculate. This calculator was made in 33 lines of code!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    # your formulas 
    if input("Continue Y/N") == "N":
         break
```

Comment: You could use `lower()` to make it work with both `n` and `N`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to add a `while` loop around your `if statements` that will continue forever or as I added, a quit option (4). Also adding a second `input prompt` at the end of the loop to reask them for the formula choice.

```
print("""
Welcome to the Science Speed, Distance, and Time Formula Caculator!

[1] Speed
[2] Distance
[3] Time
[4] Quit

Enter the number NOT the word.
""")
choice1 = int(input("Choose a Formula: "))
while(choice1 != '4'):
    if choice1 == 1:
        print("You have choosen the Speed Formula!")
        D = int(input("Enter the Distance(meters): "))
        T = int(input("Enter the Time(seconds): "))
        Equation = D/T
        print ("Your answer is ",Equation,"m/s.")
    elif choice1 == 2:
        print("You have choosen the Distance Formula!")
        S = int(input("Enter the Speed(m/s): "))
        T = int(input("Enter the Time(seconds): "))
        Equation = S*T
        print("Your answer is ",Equation,"meters.")
    elif choice1 == 3:
        print("You have choosen the Time Formula!")
        D = int(input("Enter the Distance(meters): "))
        S = int(input("Enter the Speed(m/s): "))
        Equation = D/S
        print("Your answer is ",Equation,"seconds.")
    choice1 = int(input("Choose a Formula: "))
```